# How to stop Excel from firing Worksheet_Change before Workbook_BeforeSave?

Tags: excel, events, vba

**Update: Issue Resolved**   *A colleague of mine was changing a cell during `Workbook_BeforeSave()` without disabling events, therefore triggering `Worksheet_Change()`. Yes, silly, but at least it's our fault, not Excel's*

I've noticed that whenever I hit Ctrl+S in Excel, the `Worksheet_Change()` is fired before `Workbook_BeforeSave()`. Is it possible to supress this behaviour using VBA code, but without supressing all events (i.e. without `Application.EnableEvents = false`)?

This happens regardless of what I'm doing. I've read about someone having a similar issue with ComboBoxes, but I'm not editing ComboBoxes, yet `Worksheet_Change()` fires always before saving.

Any ideas? I'm only trying to figure out how to bypass some code inside `Worksheet_Change()` when the document is saved, because that code is only supposed to be executed when the user actually changes something, not when the workbook is saved. Saving is by no means changing...

Comment: Is this on all files or just one workbook? If a single workbook dO you have any volatile functions that may be triggerd on the save in that workbook?

Comment: Only the active workbook is affected. And no, I have no volatile functions in the workbook.

Comment: Just tried with a clean workbook, and this problem does not appear. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in the first workbook, but I'm working on it. Will post whatever I find.

Comment: If you try "rebirthing" the problem workbook [by (1) selecting all sheets, right click, Move or Copy and pick (new book) for "to:book", (2) copying the code in the `ThisWorkBook` module of your problem workbook over] then does it reoccur?

Comment: Question closed. A colleague of mine was changing a cell during `Workbook_BeforeSave()` without disabling events, therefore triggering `Worksheet_Change()`. Yes, silly, but at least it's our fault, not Excel's.

Comment: @brettdj: thank you for your desire to help. I appreciate it. Your first comment, about possible volatile functions, was quite clever.

Comment: Good to hear. I had presumed that the sequence of code firing had been tested given ` Worksheet_Change() is fired before Workbook_BeforeSave()` . All's well that ends well. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It was a coding mistake on our side:

A colleague of mine was changing a cell during Workbook_BeforeSave() without disabling events, therefore triggering Worksheet_Change().

The fix was easy. In Workbook_BeforeSave():

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Some final changes
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

And that was it :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a global flag variable.

Input a function that fires when key pressed and if CTRL + S it sets flag to true.

The worksheet_change event should short circuit if this flag is true.

And workbook_aftersave should change it back to false.