# Excel inputbox reopens after entry

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

Have macro in Excel that uses application.inputbox to save date in cell. Upon entry of date the properly formated date appears in cell and then the inputbox opens again. It seems stuck in this weird loop. No matter how many times I enter the date it asks again.

Here is this section of code:

```
Function freshSTART()

redBOX.Cells(1).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter todays date: ", Title:="TODAY'S DATE", Type:=1)
redBOX.Cells(2).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter customer's name: ", Title:="CUSTOMER NAME", Type:=2)
redBOX.Cells(3).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter travel out date: ", Title:="TRAVEL OUT DATE", Type:=1)
redBOX.Cells(4).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter travel back date: ", Title:="TRAVEL BACK DATE", Type:=1)
redBOX.Cells(5).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of technicians: ", Title:="TECHNICIANS", Type:=1)
redBOX.Cells(6).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter number of engineers: ", Title:="ENGINEERS", Type:=1)
redBOX.Cells(7).Value = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter location: ", Title:="LOCATION", Type:=2)

End Function
```

Comment: How is this function being triggered? (And why not use a Sub, since this code doesn't return any value?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither you are `passing a parameter` nor are you getting a `value returned`. In that case, it's not useful to have a `function` but a `Subroutine`.

Are you calling this function on `Worksheet changed` or `Cell changed` events? Please use `Application.EnableEvents = False` when triggering functions on above events. You have to turn events off or it will keep repeating itself dragging into an infinite loop.

And then in the `change event` turn events back on.

References:

- [How to stop Excel from firing Worksheet_Change before Workbook_BeforeSave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819394/how-to-stop-excel-from-firing-worksheet-change-before-workbook-beforesave)
- [Events](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.htm)

Comment: Interesting. You're right, function is pointless. Changed to sub but problem persisted. Macro is called from workbook open. Making EnableEvents = False before the call did the trick. Don't quite understand this so clearly I have a lot to learn. Thanks for your help!