# BeforeSave loops and workbook closes

Tags: vba, excel, before-save

I am attempting to save a "copy" of a workbook by forcing a set path and filename. The following code does two things that I would like to avoid. First, the "message" is displayed twice. Why is this occurring and how can I prevent it? Second, the workbook closes after the save completes, even if I only click on the save icon. I need the workbook to stay open unless the red "x" is pressed. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 

Const Function_Area = "Benefits" 

Dim Full_Filename As String 
Dim Temp_Filename_Prefix As String 
Dim Temp_Filename_Suffix As String 
Dim Temp_Path As String 
Dim Error_Check As Boolean 
Dim End_Msg As Variant 
Dim Temp_Object As Object 

Set Temp_Object = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

With Temp_Object 
    Temp_Path = .SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" 
End With 

If Range("REVIEW_TYPE").Value = "Prototype Review" Then 
    Temp_Filename_Prefix = Range("CUSTOMER_NAME").Value & Function_Area & "_PROTO_" 
End If 
If Range("REVIEW_TYPE").Value = "Final Review" Then 
    Temp_Filename_Prefix = Range("CUSTOMER_NAME").Value & Function_Area & "_FINAL_" 
End If 
If Range("REVIEW_TYPE").Value = "Compliance Review" Then 
    Temp_Filename_Prefix = Range("CUSTOMER_NAME").Value & Function_Area & "_COMPLIANCE_" 
End If 

Temp_Filename_Suffix = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") 
Temp_Filename_Suffix = Temp_Filename_Suffix & "C" 

Full_Filename = Temp_Path & Temp_Filename_Prefix & Temp_Filename_Suffix 

End_Msg = "This file has been saved to your DESKTOP as " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _ 
Full_Filename 
End_Msg = MsgBox(End_Msg, vbInformation, "FILE SAVED") 

' Save file to Desktop

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Full_Filename, FileFormat:=52 
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True 

End Sub
```

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: You run a `.SaveAs` within a `_BeforeSave` event which triggers another `_BeforeSave` event so this is causing a loop. Try to [disable events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819394/how-to-stop-excel-from-firing-worksheet-change-before-workbook-beforesave) before you `.SaveAs`. Note that `Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"` gives you the desktop path without the need of using WScript.Shell.

Comment: What Peh said. But also, you appear to be attempting to force the user to save to their desktop, but are you wanting to do this INSTEAD of letting them choose a location or AS WELL AS? If it's INSTEAD, then adding a `Cancel = TRUE` after the SaveAs will stop them choosing their own location as well.

Comment: Thanks Peh. Your solution worked perfectly. @CLR - I incorporated your element as well since you anticipated exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just a couple of suggestions to clean up the code

you can use this in place of the three if-then statements, just to unclutter the code

```
    Dim prfx As String

    Select Case Range("REVIEW_TYPE").Value

        Case "Prototype Review":   prfx = "_PROTO_"
        Case "Final Review":       prfx = "_FINAL_"
        Case "Compliance Review":  prfx = "_COMPLIANCE_"

        Case Else:                 ' put code here, for not any of above

    End Select

    Temp_Filename_Prefix = Range("CUSTOMER_NAME").Value & Function_Area & prfx
```

also shorten the following

```
With Temp_Object 
    Temp_Path = .SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" 
End With
```

just use

```
Temp_Path = Temp_Object.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
```

also replace `& Chr(13) & Chr(10) &` with `& vbCrLf &`  or with `& vbNewLine &`