# Excel - Refreshing PivotTable data as Power Query auto refreshes PivotTable source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a database which auto refreshes and updates the table from an external source every 15 minutes. I tried the following code which updates the PivotTable every time the source data is edit/added/deleted:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("PIVOT TABLE WORKSHEET").PivotTables("PIVOT TABLE NAME").RefreshTable
End Sub
```

When i manually edit the source data, the PivotTables refresh accordingly. However, when the source data is updated **automatically** the PivotTables remain unchanged. Is there a way to make the Pivot tables refresh together with the database without the need of a user input?

Comment: I forget if this issue exists with Worksheet_Change, but that's what you'd want to use, not Worksheet_SelectionChange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have better results if you use [the `Worksheet_Change` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) instead of [the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-exce), so that the procedure runs when data changes, *not* when you select a cell with the mouse or keyboard.

> ### `Worksheet_Change` *vs.* `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events
>
> - **`Worksheet_SelectionChange`** fires when the ***selection*** changes on a worksheet.
>     For example, when the user clicks on a cell, or pushes an arrow key.
> - **`Worksheet_Change`** fires when cells on the worksheet are **changed**, either **by the user** or **by an external link**.
>
> **Note:** `Worksheet_Change does **not** occur when cells change during a re-calculation; use the`Calculate` event to trap a sheet re-calculation.)

Depending on how the data is laid out in your worksheet(s), you may want to limit the execution of this procedure by checking *which cell(s)* were changed, which is easiest overall by comparing the event procedure's `Target` parameter to a specific cell or cell-range, using the `Intersect` function.

> ### <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> Caution: Beware of infinity!
>
> When using code that changes cells within the area being "watched" by the `Worksheet_Change` event procedure, you risk entering into an infinite loop, since the change fires the event again, which changes cells again, etc.

[image]
<sup><sup>(Click [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZc2x.png) to enlarge.)</sup></sup>

There are several ways this could be avoided. This most common is to temporarily ***disable events*** with [the `Application.EnableEvents` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-enableevents-property-excel) while the *Change* event does what it needs to do.  (Don't forget to re-enable events at the end of the procedure... see example below.)

---

### Example:

Here's an untested example using all these points:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const cellsToWatch = "A1:D4"
    With Worksheets("PIVOT TABLE WORKSHEET")
        'exit the procedure if at least part of the changed cells were not within `A1:D4`
        If Application.Intersect(.Range(cellsToWatch), Target) Is Nothing Then
            'the change wasn't within `cellsToWatch`
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'disable execution of this or other events

        '----------Run your code here:--------------
        .Calculate
        .PivotTables("PIVOT TABLE NAME").RefreshTable
        '-------------------------------------------

        Application.EnableEvents = True  're-enable events
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Worksheet_Change` event** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet_SelectionChange` event** (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Application.Intersect` method** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel)
- Office Support : [**`Intercept` function** (Excel/Worksheet)](http://support.office.com/article/intercept-function-2a9b74e2-9d47-4772-b663-3bca70bf63ef)
- Stack Overflow : [**Stop Excel from firing `Worksheet_Change` before `_BeforeSave`?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8819394/8112776)
- MSDN : [**`Application.EnableEvents` property** (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-enableevents-property-excel)

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked when the main data source updates (periodically), the PivotTable updates as well. But if I use the same code on a table which takes the last 20 rows from the source (i.e INDEX/VLOOKUP) and create a PivotTable from it, the new PivotTable does not get updated. Strange!

Comment: Edit: never mind, fixed the issue was quite a trivial mistake