# Worksheet Change VBA code causing Excel to freeze

Tags: excel, vba

I created some code to run when there are changes made in certain cells. The change should trigger the code below. The problem is that when I insert data into cell F2 (or any cell from F2 through F28), a debug message pops up, but before I can read it, Excel shuts down completely. When I compiled the code, it did not show any error message. Any assistance in resolving this would be appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim DestWH As String
Dim DWHRowNum As Long
Dim dt As Date

DWHRowNum = 2
dt = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyy")

Do Until Cells(DWHRowNum, 2).Value = ""
    Select Case Cells(DWHRowNum, 6).Value
        Case Is = "ABQ1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "BFI4"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        Case Is = "CLE2"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "DEN3"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "DEN4"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        Case Is = "GEG1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "LIT1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "ORD5"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "ORF3"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "PAE2"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "PCW1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "PDX9"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
        Case Is = "SLC1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "17:00"
        Case Is = "SMF1"
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 7).Value = dt + 1
            Cells(DWHRowNum, 8).Value = "04:30"
    End Select
    DWHRowNum = DWHRowNum + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Excel from firing Worksheet_Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819394/how-to-stop-excel-from-firing-worksheet-change-before-workbook-beforesave)

Comment: After I input data into one of the triggering cells the correct results are returned to the correct cells as per the code, but then a quick flash of the error dialog box and Excel closes. Adding the event disabler code suggested everything seems fine. Thank you.